Paho client exception:Internal error, caused by no new message IDs being available
I was using the Spring-Integration-mqtt module to send and receive MQTT messages and the following exception occurred:
2024-10-22 10:56:45.161 [][] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler:250 - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failed to publish to MQTT in the [bean 'mqttOutboundHandler' for component 'mqttOutboundFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/rms/config/mqtt/MqttConfig.class]'; from source: 'com.rms.config.mqtt.MqttConfig.mqttOutboundHandler(org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttConnectionOptions)'], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"value":[],"unitId":741,"fieldName":"landingCall-down-front-1-32","isRunningData":false,"isError":false}, headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, errorChannel=, mqtt_qos=0, id=1237ba75-e408-10ff-e322-5f692dd8970e, mqtt_topic=status/741/landingCall-down-front-1-32, timestamp=1729565799271}]
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.publish(Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.java:283)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:311)
Caused by: Internal error, caused by no new message IDs being available (32001)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState.getNextMessageId(ClientState.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientState.send(ClientState.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms.internalSend(ClientComms.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient.publish(MqttAsyncClient.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttAsyncClient.publish(MqttAsyncClient.java:1499)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.publish(Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.java:271)
    ... 10 more

I use OpenJDK21,Spring6,SpringBoot3.2.5,PahoMQTT1.2.5 as dev-environment;
The following is my core logic. I configured two Mqtt clients using Spring-Integration integration flow. One is used to receive information, and the other is used to send messages. The frequency of sending messages is about 5000 messages per second.
mqtt:
  client-id-inbound: rms-inbound
  client-id-outbound: rms-outbound
  url: tcp://127.0.0.1:1883
  username: rms
  password: 123456

package com.rms.config.mqtt;

import com.rms.domain.entity.Prop;
import com.rms.protocol.CanProtocolLoader;
import com.rms.service.LogService;
import io.netty.handler.codec.mqtt.MqttQoS;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.IMqttAsyncClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.MqttConnectionOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Transformers;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.ClientManager;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.Mqttv5ClientManager;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.*;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan("com.rms.config")
@Slf4j
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mqtt")
@Data
public class MqttConfig {
    private String clientIdInbound;
    private String clientIdOutbound;
    private String url;
    private String password;
    private String username;
    @Bean
    public MqttConnectionOptions mqttConnectOptions(){
        MqttConnectionOptions options = new MqttConnectionOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { url});
        options.setUserName(username);
        options.setPassword(password.getBytes());
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        return options;
    }
    @Bean
    public ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> clientManager(MqttConnectionOptions options) {
        Mqttv5ClientManager clientManager = new Mqttv5ClientManager(options, clientIdInbound);
        clientManager.setPersistence(new MqttDefaultFilePersistence());
        return clientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageConverter simpleMessageConverter(){
        return new SimpleMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler mqttOutboundHandler(MqttConnectionOptions connectionOptions) {
        Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler messageHandler = new Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler(connectionOptions,clientIdOutbound);
        messageHandler.setAsync(true);
        messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("defaultTopic");
        messageHandler.setDefaultQos(MqttQoS.AT_MOST_ONCE.value());
        messageHandler.setConverter(simpleMessageConverter());
        return messageHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttOutboundFlow(MessageHandler mqttOutboundHandler){
        return IntegrationFlow.from("mqttOutboundChannel")
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()))
                .handle(mqttOutboundHandler)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow statusInboundFlow(ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> clientManage){
        Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter messageProducer  =
                new Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(clientManage, "status/+/#");
        return IntegrationFlow.from(messageProducer)
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Prop.class))
                .route(Prop.class,prop->{
                    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(prop.getIsError())){
                        return "errorDataChannel";
                    }
                    else if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(prop.getIsRunningData())){
                        return "runningDataChannel";
                    }
                    else {
                        return "discardChannel";
                    }
                })
                .get();
    }
    @Bean
    public CanProtocolLoader canProtocolLoader(){
        return new CanProtocolLoader();
    }
    @Bean
    public UnitErrorHandler errorLogHandler(LogService logService ){
        return new UnitErrorHandler(logService);
    }
    @Bean
    public UnitRunningDataHandler unitRunningDataHandler(LogService logService){
        return new UnitRunningDataHandler(logService);
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorLogChannelFlow(UnitErrorHandler unitErrorHandler){
        return IntegrationFlow.from("errorDataChannel")
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()))
                .handle(unitErrorHandler)
                .get();
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow runningDataChannelFlow(UnitRunningDataHandler runningDataHandler){
        return IntegrationFlow.from("runningDataChannel")
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()))
                .handle(runningDataHandler)
                .get();
    }
  
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow discardChannelFlow(){
        return IntegrationFlow.from("discardChannel")
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()))
                .handle(message -> {
                })
                .get();
    }
}
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UnitErrorHandler implements MessageHandler {
    private final LogService logService;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        Prop<?> prop = (Prop<?>) message.getPayload();
        logService.saveErrorLog(prop);
    }

}

I use the MessagingGateway annotation to direct messages to my mqttOutboundChannel so I can use MqttGateway to send mqtt messages
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public interface MqttGateway {
    void sendToMqtt(String data);

    void sendToTopic(String payload, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC)String topic);

    void sendToTopic(String payload, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC)String topic,@Header(MqttHeaders.QOS ) int qos);
    void sendWithResp(String payload, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC)String topic,@Header(MqttHeaders.RESPONSE_TOPIC) String responseTopic,@Header(MqttHeaders.QOS ) int qos);
}



When the message delivery rate is very low, generally less than 200 messages per second, the error I mentioned at the beginning will not occur, but when I increase the message production rate to 5,000.
When I removed the inbound part of mqtt messages, I found that the program worked very well without any errors. Once I introduced the statusInboundFlow integrated flow in the above code, the mqtt outbound client could not send messages normally and a large number of messages appeared. The exception mentioned before
I expect that according to the above logic, I can send and receive MQTT messages normally

Have a look at https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/323 but this implies you have more than 65535 messages in flight at a time from a single client.

I see there is a logic like this in the Paho client:
    } else if (message instanceof MqttPublish) {
        if (((MqttPublish) message).getMessage().getQos() == 0) {
            // once a QoS 0 message is sent we can clean up its records straight away as
            // we won't be hearing about it again
            token.internalTok.markComplete(null, null);
            callback.asyncOperationComplete(token);
            decrementInFlight();
            releaseMessageId(message.getMessageId());
            tokenStore.removeToken(message);
            checkQuiesceLock();
        }
    }

So, how about setting that messageHandler.setDefaultQos() as 0?
Otherwise, please, share with us a simple project we can reproduce and play with.
More over this sounds like Paho client concern, not Spring Integration.
Another workaround I may suggest is like use different client instances for receive and produce. Not use that shared ClientManager for your inbound and outbound channel adapters.
UPDATE
I cannot reproduce it on my side, but I definitely see some race condition. Will fix it shortly on Spring Integration side.
I did this chance into your project:
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttOutboundFlow(MessageHandler mqttOutboundHandler){
    var requestHandlerRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    requestHandlerRetryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(RetryTemplate.builder().maxAttempts(10).fixedBackoff(1000).build());
    return IntegrationFlow.from("mqttOutboundChannel")
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()))
            .handle(mqttOutboundHandler, e -> e.advice(requestHandlerRetryAdvice))
            .get();
}

See if RequestHandlerRetryAdvice can help you somehow to mitigate that msgId problem.
I also see that you do:
messageProducer.setManualAcks(true);

But does not look like you really ack those message anywhere manually...

I'm considering providing a minimal case, plus you mentioned"Not use that shared ClientManager for your inbound and outbound channel adapters." The outbound client and inbound client I use in my code use different IDs, and I take it for granted that there will be different client instances for such a method. Am I wrong in my understanding? What is the recommended approach if I want to use different client instances for inbound and outbound? Thanks

Oh! Sorry, I missed the fact that your Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler is created against a MqttConnectionOptions, not that ClientManager. So, yeah, your channel adapters does not share the client. Looks like something else is there in the Paho client for the publisher side. And from here it sounds like the reproducer might be much simpler - just a Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler part since that's where you are suffering according to stack trace. Plus I see you use virtual threads. Perhaps Paho library is not ready for that as well...

So, according to the internal logic if the Paho client the QoS can be only 0, 1 or 2. See if you are on the same page.

OK. I see you said When I removed the inbound part of mqtt messages. But with different IMqttAsyncClient instances for those channel adapters that does not make sense. They just don't share ClientState to interfere with the same inUseMsgIds map.

I have written a minimal use case to reproduce my above error. Please check it out:
https://github.com/129duckflew/inte-paho-test.git    Thanks

Thank you for the sample! I had to do some changes to make it running on my side, but still good to play with. Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.
